# How does 'unless' mean 'or'?

Tags: etymology, unless

<sub>Source: p 319, *A Concise Introduction to Logic* (12 Ed, 2014), by Patrick Hurley</sub>

> in propositional logic it is usually simpler to equate “unless”
>   with “or.”

In and using only ordinary English (and no Logic), how can 'unless' be interpreted to mean 'or'? Can semantic change explain how 'unless' = 'or'?

I wish to understand how 'unless' = 'or' directly and intuitively. So please do `not` refer to or use the alternative (Stipulative) definition that 'unless' = 'if not'.

> [unless](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/215075?redirectedFrom=unless#eid16548703) = [†](http://public.oed.com/how-to-use-the-oed/key-to-symbols-and-other-conventions/)1. prep.phr. On a less or lower condition, requirement, footing, etc., than (what is specified). With preceding negative, expressed or implied.

<sub>PS: I quoted the obsolete definition above, because I wish to understand 'unless' from first principles and because all the other definitions use some variant of 'if not'.</sub>

Comment: *I will go to sleep unless she calls* means either she will call *or* I will go to sleep. In formal logic, therefore, the first statement can be reduced to *I will go to sleep, or she calls* when you write out the formula. But you cannot simply swap out *unless* for *or* in ordinary English, because language is *not* about reducing statements to equations. Otherwise, we would never have had to invent propositional logic in the first place.

Comment: Note to self: See http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22059303, http://brianbuccola.com/the-semantics-of-unless/, http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=59813.

Comment: [Although ‘P unless Q’ is frequently meant to convey `P exclusive-or Q`, its literal meaning is just `P or Q`.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/612312/484417)

Comment: **unless** is complemented by a clause that refers to a *sufficient condition* for something to occur (or not occur):   *I will get some sleep unless you need my help.*  If you need my help, I won't get some sleep but will remain awake, otherwise (i.e. if you don't need my help) I will go to bed.

Comment: It is not clear what kind of an answer the OP expected here, and why the question is specifically about *unless*, which is  far from being the only word of ordinary language that loses some of its meaning when it is replaced by an operator of formal logic.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "in propositional logic" is a specialist use - this would be better served by being on the mathematics SE

Comment: @Greybeard, while there may be good reasons for closing this question, its being about 'a specialist use' of the word is not one of them. The word *unless* does not have a specialised use in logic; in fact, it does not have a use in it at all. The question concerns the way in which the meaning that *unless* has **in ordinary language** is treated in formal logic.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one situation where *unless* can mean *or*.

> Take this book back to the library **unless** you renew it.
>
> Either take this book back to the library **or** renew it.

There are lots of other situations where you cannot replace **unless** with **or** in everyday speech.

For example,

> Take an umbrella **unless** it is sunny.

Because being sunny is a condition you have no control over, and it's your decision to take the umbrella or not, it doesn't work to rewrite this sentence with **or**. If you try to, you're stuck with something like:

> Either take an umbrella **or** it is sunny,

which makes no sense at all.

Comment: Ordinary propositional logic (the kind that is taught in introductory-logic courses) is not intended to handle imperatives (which are not propositions in the relevant sense). There are the forms of logic that do, but they are several layers of complexity away from the context in which this question was asked.

Answer (score 0):

The word **unless** evolved from a prepositional phrase "on less than {something}" and expressed a threshold condition, as in this example from an imaginary conversation 600 years ago:

> On less than fire, don't wake me up.

So in branching representation:

```
if there is no fire
  let me sleep
else
  wake me up
```

or

```
if there is a fire
  wake me up
else
  let me sleep
```

Nowadays we can say:

> Don't wake me up unless there's a fire.

Answer (score -1):

"Unless" does not equal "or" 'directly and intuitively'.

Comment: Can you please transform this into a comment, and delete it as an answer? If the answer really is 'no', then I wish to leave this question unanswered lest some linguist in the future discovers the intuition.